# Claims-based authorization in MVC 5 using Google OAuth2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, google-oauth, claims-based-identity

Having implemented Google OAuth2 via OWIN, I have a question about Claims in general.

We need a ton of Claims, in order to set up Claims-Based *Authorization*. Note that this is NOT about Claims-based *Authentication*. Google only supplies a few Claims, like email, name, etc.

We need a lot more Claims, so that we can control access to resources (*Authorization*). Having read Microsoft's documentation, and an associated e-book they have published, they say this:

> Because claims involve an explicit trust relationship with an issuer,
>   your application believes a claim about the current user only if it
>   trusts the entity that issued the claim.
>   See here: [An Introduction To Claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359101.aspx)

My inclination was to add custom Claims to the AspNetUserClaims table. In fact, I have done this, and associated the Claims to the AspNetUser created by the integration with Google. However, this feels tantamount to a forgery at this point, because Google has not issued these Claims, our enterprise has. It seems that the spirit of the Claims concept is to "trust the issuer". Which entity is regarded as the issuer of the Claim? Is this hybrid approach, adding Claims to Identities authenticated via external issuers, an accepted approach? I can't see how else to extend the limited information provided by Google (which works great for Identity), other than manually adding Claims from within our own enterprise to these externally-authenticated users.

Incidentally, every Claim found in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims shows the Issuer and OriginalIssuer as "LOCAL AUTHORITY"...nothing about Google.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your question here. The external identity claims (from Google+, in this case), have nothing to do with the user claims in Identity. It's two separate concepts. You can use the claims from the OAuth channel to populate your application user claims, but at the end of the day, the claims are those of your application.

Comment: OK, so even though Google is the trusted authority for authentication, once the Claims are stored in our system (regardless if we got them originally from Google), all of the Claims are ours?

Comment: Yep. Your application is the trusted authority for your applications claims. It doesn't matter where they might have come from originally, once you created a claim in your app, you're the trusted authority for that value.

Comment: @ChrisPratt If you like, make this an answer and I will accept it.